# How to save image path in database and save image in specific folder of project.NET core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

```
          [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Employee emp)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
                foreach (var Image in files)
                {
                    if (Image != null && Image.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var file = Image;
                        var root = _appEnvironment.WebRootPath;
 var uploads = "uploads\\img";
                        if (file.Length > 0)
                        {
                            // you can change the Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "")
                            // to Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") it will produce the same result
                            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

                            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(root, uploads, fileName), FileMode.Create))
                            {
                                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                                // This will produce uploads\img\fileName.ext
                                emp.ImageUrl = Path.Combine(uploads, fileName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                db.Add(emp);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
            }
            return View(emp);
        }
```

HTML

```
 <input asp-for="ImageUrl" type="file" Class="form-control" />
```

when i save image, image save successfully in database, but it takes full image path like this C:\Users\VIZO\Desktop\employee.jpg i dont want like this, i need to save image path something like this ~images\employee.jpg. The other problem is image doesnt saving in specific folder of project, i need to save image in this path of my project

uploads\img

Answer (score 0):

So basically your `_appEnvironment.WebRootPath` by default will be: 
`%PathToProject%/wwwroot`.
For the filePath on your database i would do something like this:

```
 var root = _appEnvironment.WebRootPath
 var uploads = "uploads\\img";
 if (file.Length > 0)
 {
   // you can change the Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "")
   // to Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") it will produce the same result
   var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

   using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(root, uploads, fileName), FileMode.Create))
   {
     await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
     // This will produce uploads\img\fileName.ext
     emp.BookPic = Path.Combine(uploads, fileName);                                           
   }
 }
```

If you require any more clarification or guidance please feel free to comment and allow me to explain in more detail.

Thanks.

Comment: i have just tried your code still same issue in database its saving full path like this - C:\Users\VIZO\Desktop\employee.jpg and picture doesn't come to my project folder which is uploads/img

Comment: could you print what you get out of Path.Combine and paste it here? Also on the using i had forgotten to add the root as the first argument of the Path.Combine.  Also could you make a print for `Path.Combine(root, uploads, fileName)` i have the same code running on my machine and all goes smooth.

Comment: i have edited code in above question can you check code and tell me am i doing correct? i have also copied my html code

Comment: have you checked?

Comment: have you checked code that i have edited in question is it corrrect?

Comment: Yep your code is fine. Now maybe the problem you are facing with the change of the FileName on `emp.ImageUrl` maybe it has something to do with the `asp-for="ImageUrl" ` you are using on your input tag.

Comment: so in input tag i should write like this ? <input name ="ImageUrl" type="file" Class="form-control" />

Comment: I would completely change the name to something like image or file.

Comment: you are still using the name="ImageUrl" i would change this to name="image".

Comment: i have imageUrl property in my database and in my class so thats why i am using same.name

Comment: Yes I know that. But you are setting the property on your controller. So it does not need to be setted through the html form

Comment: ok i just need to know what will be my html code? as i think i am doing somehting wrong in html code. Can you write down html code for me?